# Possible to get used maven version to insert into a filtered resource file?

Tags: maven-2, filter, properties

I wonder, if it is possible to get currently used version of maven for filtering resource file.

I've a resource file, that is filtered by maven:

```
version=${project.version}
buildDate=${timestampFormatted}
buildBy=${user.name}
name=${project.artifactId}
buildVersion=${build.number}
osName=${os.name}
osArch=${os.arch}
osVersion=${os.version}
fileEncoding=${file.encoding}
```

and now I would prefer to save currently used maven version, too.

Is there any thing like `${maven.version}`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) can do this. Check out the [build-helper:maven-version](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/maven-version-mojo.html) goal, it sets a property containing the current version of maven (`maven.version` by default).

For example, the following pom sets the property and then uses the property to save the maven version to the project jar's manifest.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>maven-version</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>maven-version</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Maven-Version>${maven.version}</Maven-Version>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```